# Error while importing ggplot in Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-8.1, python-ggplot

The pip installation went fine but when I try to import the module into the shell i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from ggplot import *   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\ggplot\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .qplot import qplot   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\ggplot\qplot.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .geoms import geom_point, geom_bar, geom_histogram, geom_line   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\ggplot\geoms\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .geom_density import geom_density   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\ggplot\geoms\geom_density.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 324, in <module>
    from .stats import *   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 242, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 531, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm a total beginner so don't rule out obvious stuff.